# Macro to select data from multiple workbooks and copy into one master workbook with different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in macro. I have wrote one macro to pick up certain data from one workbook and copy into a master workbook. I tried to write macro to pick up same type of data from multiple workbooks and copy into the master workbook in different worksheets but failed. The workbooks are all located in one folder. Can someone help me? Below is my macro:

```
Sub Summary()
    Dim LastRow As Long, x As Range
    Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook
    Dim criteria1 As String
    Dim criteria2 As String
    Dim criteria3 As String
    Dim criteria4 As String
          
    Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("D:\Documents\BS\BankABCBS.xls")
    Set w = extwbk.Worksheets(1).Range("V:V")
    Set x = extwbk.Worksheets(1).Range("X:X")
    Set v = extwbk.Worksheets(1).Range("T:T")
    Set y = extwbk.Worksheets(1).Range("AV:AV")
    Set Z = extwbk.Worksheets(1).Range("BB:BB")
    Set S = extwbk.Worksheets(1).Range("BR:BR")
     
 
    With twb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    criteria1 = "<>*COMPANY 1*"
    criteria2 = "<>*COMPANY 2*"
    criteria3 = "<>*COMPANY 3*"
    criteria4 = "<>*BankABC*"
    
               
            
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(6, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(6, 3)), Z, criteria1, Z, criteria2, Z, criteria3)
            .Cells(6, 5) = Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(6, 3)), Z, criteria1, Z, criteria2, Z, criteria3)
            .Cells(7, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(7, 3)), Z, criteria1, Z, criteria2, Z, criteria3)
            .Cells(7, 5) = Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(7, 3)), Z, criteria1, Z, criteria2, Z, criteria3)
            .Cells(8, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(8, 3)), x, "<>*returning bank*")
            .Cells(8, 5) = Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(8, 3)), x, "<>*returning bank*")
            .Cells(9, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(9, 3)), x, "*returning bank*")
            .Cells(9, 5) = Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(9, 3)), x, "*returning bank*")
            .Cells(10, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(10, 3)))
            .Cells(10, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(10, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(11, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(11, 3))) + Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, "*Same Day Credit*")
            .Cells(11, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(11, 3)), v), 2) + TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, "*Same Day Credit*", v), 2)
            .Cells(12, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(12, 3)))
            .Cells(12, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(12, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(13, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(13, 3)))
            .Cells(13, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(13, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(14, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(14, 3)))
            .Cells(14, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(14, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(15, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(15, 3)), y, criteria4, Z, "*COMPANY 1*") + Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(15, 3)), y, criteria4, Z, "*COMPANY 2*") + Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(15, 3)), y, criteria3, Z, "*COMPANY 3*")
            .Cells(15, 5) = Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(15, 3)), y, criteria4, Z, "*COMPANY 1*") + Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(15, 3)), y, criteria4, Z, "*COMPANY 2*") + Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(15, 3)), y, criteria3, Z, "*COMPANY 3*")
            .Cells(16, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(16, 3)), y, "*COMPANY 3*", Z, "*COMPANY 3*") + Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(16, 3)), y, "*BankABC*", Z, "*COMPANY 1*") + Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(16, 3)), y, "*BankABC*", Z, "*COMPANY 2*")
            .Cells(16, 5) = Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(16, 3)), y, "*COMPANY 3*", Z, "*COMPANY 3*") + Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(16, 3)), y, "*BankABC*", Z, "*COMPANY 1*") + Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(16, 3)), y, "*BankABC*", Z, "*COMPANY 2*")
            .Cells(19, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(19, 3)), S, "")
            .Cells(19, 5) = Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(19, 3)), S, "")
            .Cells(20, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(20, 3)), S, "*FED*") + Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(20, 3)), S, "*CHIPS*")
            .Cells(20, 5) = Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(20, 3)), S, "*FED*") + Application.SumIfs(v, w, (.Cells(20, 3)), S, "*CHIPS*")
            .Cells(21, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(21, 3)))
            .Cells(21, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(21, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(22, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(22, 3)))
            .Cells(22, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(22, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(23, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(23, 3)))
            .Cells(23, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(23, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(24, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(24, 3))) + Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, "*CHECK OVERRIDE*")
            .Cells(24, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(24, 3)), v), 2) + TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, "*CHECK OVERRIDE*", v), 2)
            .Cells(25, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(25, 3)))
            .Cells(25, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(25, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(26, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(26, 3)))
            .Cells(26, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(26, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(27, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(27, 3)))
            .Cells(27, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(27, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(28, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(28, 3)))
            .Cells(28, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(28, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(29, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(29, 3)))
            .Cells(29, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(29, 3)), v), 2)
            .Cells(30, 4) = Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, (.Cells(30, 3))) + Application.CountIfs(v, "<>" & "", w, "*INTEREST*")
            .Cells(30, 5) = TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, (.Cells(30, 3)), v), 2) + TRUEROUND(Application.SumIf(w, "*INTEREST*", v), 2)
    End With

        
    twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(38, 5).Value = TRUEROUND(Application.Sum(v), 2)
    twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(38, 4).Value = TRUEROUND(Application.Count(v), 0)
        
    extwbk.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Each workbook has only one worksheet. How to make my macro run for all 20 workbooks without opening each workbooks?

Comment: Welcome to SO. *but failed* is too broad. You need to focus on problem. Also, post only relevants parts of code. Also, please, about macro run for all 20 workbooks, with a loop it should be enough. There are plenty of examples here on SO

Comment: Please provide the code that tries to open multiple workbooks, provide debug details on what is exactly the error (failure) and any debug details